# Cross validated $R^2$ and the adjusted $R^2$?

Tags: cross-validation, r-squared

What are the similarities and differences between cross validated $R^2$ and adjusted $R^2$?

Comment: I can think of several different ways to construct a "cross-validated $R^2$."  What exactly do you mean by this?

Answer (score 2):

Both allow you to compare models. But.

**Cross-validated $R^2$** is likely to give you the $R^2$ you would observe generalizing your model to unseen data (provided the distributions of the train data and the test data remain the same).

**Adjusted $R^2$** is a way to compare models, possibly helps you to pick up the best, penalizing them for the number of predictors they use. This does not give you any hint regarding the performance of the models on new data.

Answer (score -2):

When you add more predictors to your regression model, the classical R2 artificially increases for the same prediction quality. That's why there is an adjusted one. You can find more information on [Minitab's blog](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/multiple-regession-analysis-use-adjusted-r-squared-and-predicted-r-squared-to-include-the-correct-number-of-variables)

Comment: Your Answer doesn't really address the question of the OP, which is what are differences/similarities between a cross-validated $R^2$ and the adjusted $R^2$.